# how to remove password suggestion Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

When I am trying to change password in Chrome, there is always a dropdown list with "Use password for:" options. Is it possible to remove it? I have tried autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="false" but without success.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute), if you expect a new password to be filled in (which is why you would not expect auto-completion for example), you should rather specify `autocomplete="new-password"` for the input field.

This instruction is recognized by chrome.

Comment: on chrome `Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)` not working

Comment: this activates the functionality of google chrome that suggest a new strong password... so I mark this answer as useful, thanks

Comment: This does not actually work completely. When using autocomplete="new-password" Chrome will not autofill the password, but will suggest the stored password and provide an option to generate a strong password. This is not sufficient when creating a "Change Password" form since you do not want to allow other people to fill in the existing password. "new-password" should be turning off any ability to get the current password except by typing it.

Answer (score 2):

[They reported this as a bug in the Chromium project](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352347), but seems Google never actually looked at it or fixed it.

A workaround would be to change the name of the field.

You can also add invisible input fields, [a demo could be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/2540618).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem it seems difficult to solve I found a solution
To solve the problem, 
the `input` in **initialization** must be equal to `type="text"` and then change to `type="password"` with the first focus or insert input

```js
function changeTypeInput(inputElement){ 
  inputElement.type="password" 
}
```

```html
<input type="text"
  id="anyUniqueId"  
  onfocus="changeTypeInput(this)"
  oninput="changeTypeInput(this)"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the password to text and onclick function to again change as password

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="old_password" required onclick="$(this).attr('type', 'password');">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34331740)